# ClaimsPrincipal.User in HubContext is null

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

At the moment I'm currently using the AspNetCore SignalR, where I expose the /notify in the MapHub in the endpoint along with a secure endpoint with the [Authorize] attribute. I tried several solutions that were posted here in SO but no to avail. And the objective on my current situation is to get Context.User in the Hub where it has a user and to secure the /notify endpoint. So currently right now the ClaimsPrincipal User doesn't have any user in it after passing on the token in the OnMessageReceived. And this project uses the AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi with Azure AD

Below are the current codes that was written

NotificationHub.cs

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub<INotificationHub>
{
        public string GetConnectionId() => Context.ConnectionId;
        public string GetUserId() => Context.UserIdentifier;
        public ClaimsPrincipal GetUser() => Context.User;
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)

                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
                {
                    Configuration.Bind(IdentityConstants.AzureAd, options);
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = IdentityClaimTypes.Roles;

                    if (options.Events == null)
                    {
                        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents();
                    }

                    var tokenValidatedHandler = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;

                    options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                    {
                        if (tokenValidatedHandler != null)
                        {
                            await tokenValidatedHandler(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }
                    };

                    options.Events.OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && path.StartsWithSegments("/notif"))
                        {
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };

                }, options => Configuration.Bind(IdentityConstants.AzureAd, options))
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(options => Configuration.Bind(IdentityConstants.AzureAd, options))
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection(GraphOptions.ConfigurationSection))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

The sequence in the startup is it first starts with as follows
services.AddAuthentication -> services.AddAuthorization -> services.AddSignalR

and I added the

```
services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameUserIdProvider>();
```

at the bottom of the ConfigureServices

Which part did I miss? I tried several solutions on this like creating a configure services of JwtBearerOptions like below

```
            services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            Func<MessageReceivedContext, Task> existingOnMessageReceivedHandler = options.Events.OnMessageReceived;
            options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "preferred_username";
            options.SaveToken = true;

            var tokenValidatedHandler = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;

            options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
            {
                if (tokenValidatedHandler != null)
                {
                    await tokenValidatedHandler(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            };

            options.Events.OnMessageReceived = async context =>
            {
                await existingOnMessageReceivedHandler(context);

                StringValues accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                PathString path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;

                If the request is for our hub...
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && path.StartsWithSegments("/notif"))
                    {
                        Read the token out of the query string
                    context.Token = accessToken;
                    }
            };
        });
```

Hope someone can shed some insights on where I miss or what I am lacking. Thank you in advance.